# Installing qt5 Taking a long time with Brew

Tags: macos, qt, installation, homebrew

Has anyone had the problem of installing qt5 taking longer than expected?

```
gerudian:vra-rails alvincrespo$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
gerudian:vra-rails alvincrespo$ brew install qt5
==> Downloading http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/qt5-5.0.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure -prefix /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.0.2 -system-libpng -system-zlib -confirm-license -opensource -nomake demos -nomake examples -arch x86_64 -release
==> make
```

Comment: How long is "expected"? Especially when building QtWebkit, it can take quite some time.

Comment: I'm trying to install it right now and it's taking long but it's also eating up a s*** load of hard drive space while compiling. I'm talking in the 5-6gb range, is _that_ to be expected? :)

Comment: Yeah, it takes a while on my Macbook Pro pegging the CPU at 100% the whole time, but it did eventually finish.
usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.0.1: 3284 files, 143M, built in 27.7 minutes

Comment: `/Users/phrogz/.homebrew/Cellar/qt/4.8.6: 2790 files, 122M, built in 24.8 minutes`. 100% CPU, fans on full, but it did get there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more smalltalk than a real question.

Answer (score 7):

it took 29 minutes for me, on a MacBook Pro i7 16G RAM with SSD.

Answer (score 6):

Mine took over six hours... mid-2011 Mac mini i5 (dual core) 8GB RAM

> **brew reinstall qt5 --with-docs --with-examples**
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2: 26,937 files, 876M, built in 385 minutes 26 seconds

Comment: and the compilation use approximately 27GB !

Answer (score 2):

1.5 hrs for me on my Mid-2010 MacBook Pro 2.66GHz i7 4GB memory:

> /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6: 2793 files, 121M, built in 87.4 minutes

Answer (score 1):

The result on my MacBook Pro Core i5 at 2.3GHz with 4GB RAM was:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6: 2791 files, 121M, built in 76.6 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Results from a Late 2013 Mac Pro, 12 2.7 Ghz cores and 64 GB of ECC RAM:

> /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.0: 6310 files, 287M, built in 27.2
>   minutes

Answer (score 1):

Results from a Mid 2013 Macbook Air w/ 1.3 GHz dual-core i5 (4250U) with 4 GB of RAM.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.0: 6310 files, 285M, built in 187.7 minutes
```

I gotta say, I almost gave up around the 2 hour mark.

Answer (score 1):

My results on Mid-2009 MacBook Pro with 2,53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo und 8 GB ram.

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.0: 24683 files, 756M, built in 427.5 minutes
```

That's more than 7 hours! Why did it take that long?
Probably because I compiled with these options:

```
brew install qt5 --with-docs --with-examples --with-developer --with-d-bus
```

Answer (score 0):

It took nearly **1.5 hours** on a Late-2008 MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo at 2.8GHz with 8GB of memory!

> /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6: 2793 files, 119M, built in 82.7 minutes

Answer (score 0):

White 2008 penryn macbook 2.4GHz Core 2 Due with 2GB RAM:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1: 2795 files, 121M, built in 147.0 minutes
```

pyqt was another ~20 min on top.